# Storing day of week with time in database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

Storing day of week and  time only in database saves `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
expected data should be like `Monday 8:30 AM`,

Stored procedure

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`192.168.21.%` PROCEDURE `AddDay`(d DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tbl_days`(`day`) VALUES(d);
END
```

C# Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(cmbDay.Text.Trim()).Append(" ");
            sb.Append(cmbHour.Text.Trim()).Append(":");
            sb.Append(cmbMinutes.Text.Trim()).Append(" ");
            sb.Append(cmbTime.Text.Trim());

            string day = sb.ToString();
```

Issue will be solved if I change the datatype from `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`, How can fix this issue? or should I just use `VARCHAR`?

Comment: you should follow best practice and store as datetime...

Comment: Do not ever store logical dates/times/etc as varchar. **Don't do it.**

Comment: @Patashu, I see, so how can I fix the issue?

Comment: @SHINHAN With a debugger. If `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is being saved to the database, it sounds like you're attempting to insert a valid date, which mysql will convert to all 0s. Is your data correct? Are the dates that you send to the SQL query after building them with your string builder correct? etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to store this value in the database.  Remember that you can always retrieve the day of week in SQL, like:

- using the `DAYNAME` command:

  `SELECT DAYNAME(day) FROM tbl_days`
- using the `DAYFORMAT` command:

  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(day, '%W');`

More information at the MySQL Reference Manual for the [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[EDIT]:  You can declare the `day` column type as `TIMESTAMP`, then your `INSERT` query could be something like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_days (day) VALUES (NOW());
```

or have an explicit input such as:

```
SET @date = CONCAT($year,'-',$month,'-',$day,'-',$hour,'-',$minute,'-',$second);
INSERT INTO tbl_days (day) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%Y-%c-%e-%k-%i-%s'));
```

Comment: No, the user needs to save datetime in database sample: Monday 8:00 AM

Comment: I would agree with GregD: you should store the value in regular DateTime format and use SELECT statement to extract the information about day name.

Comment: @SHINHAN: if this is the requirement (though it seems a bit strange), then you can create a trigger that will extract the dayname (as suggested by GregD) and store it in additional field on data entry event (or whatever event you use to trigger the procedure)

Comment: @SHINHAN The user needs it to be saved under such format in the database or to be displayed in such format in the application?

Comment: @SHINHAN - yes, but for a long run it would be much better to store the values as `TIMESTAMP` value rather than `VARCHAR`.  In the future you never know what else you want to do with these values and the `TIMESTAMP` give you just a bit more flexibility.